# Квантификаторы в perl

Tags: perl

Что-то ничего не могу понять. К примеру, возьмем код:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
while (1)
{
    print "Введите время: ";
    chomp ($wr = <STDIN>);

    if ($wr =~ /[0-2]{2}/)
    {
        print "\nВсе верно\n"
    }
    else
    {
        print "\nНе работает\n";
    }
}
```

По идее, должно пролазить тока две цифры, состоящие из 0 по 2 включительно. Почему проходят 22222? 22222222222222222222222222?

Comment: Так, хорошо. Но почему? Двойка по идее итак ясно говорит, что цифры должно быть две. Зачем нужно еще уточнять "начало-конец"?

Comment: Потому что регулярка проходит по всей строке, а в строке у тебя множество "двух двоек". Почитай про регулярки более подробно хотя бы и в википедии.

Answer (score 5):

Так сделай

```
 if ($wr =~ /^[0-2]{2}$/)
```

Comment: Это правильный ответ.

Comment: Т.е. 9 часов ввести нельзя...

Answer (score 3):

*Как* сделать, вам уже ответили. Осталось объяснить *почему*.

Строка совпадёт с указанным вами шаблоном /[0-2]{2}/ в тех случаях, когда в *любом* месте такой строки попадётся последовательность двух цифр от нуля до двойки. Предложенные вами строки '22222' и '2222222222222222' удовлетворяют этому условию.

Шаблон /^[0-2]{2}$/ означает, что ни до нулей с двойками, ни после них не должно быть ничего — поэтому такому регулярному выражению будет удовлетворять строка '22', но не '22222'.

В документации по перлу есть страницы, посвящённые регулярным выражениям:

- [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) — Perl regular expressions, the rest of the story
- perlrequick — Perl regular expressions quick start
- perlreref — Perl regular expressions quick reference
- perlrebackslash — Perl regular expression backslash sequences
- perlrecharclass — Perl regular expression character classes
- perlretut — Perl regular expressions tutorial

Кстати, ваш пример можно упростить:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -nlw

BEGIN { print 'Enter time: ' }

print /^[0-2]{2}$/  ? 'OK' : 'Fail';
```

Что означают -n и -l — смотрите man [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Comment: Это "упрощение" вредит читабельности. Так что лучше не упрощать ;)

Comment: Это - не вредит, здесь как раз разумное сокращение кода.  А первый вариант - это не Perl, это C :-)

Comment: Тем не менее первый код более читабелен - хоть он и далёк от идеала, но по крайней мере не заставляет лезть в perldoc и выяснять назначение аргументов командной строки. Впрочем, для Вас, видимо, чем запутаннее программа на Perl, тем лучше.

Кстати, использование -w - это моветон, в современном Perl используют use warnings;

Comment: Не надо мешать в одну кучу нечитаемый код и использование возможностей языка. Нечитаемо - это патч Бармина на Perl :-) А в perldoc нужно не "заглядывать", а изучать, желательно до того, как что-то писать. Хотя бы для того, чтобы знать язык, на котором пишешь. Иначе самые простейшие конструкции будут казаться абракадаброй. 

Что же касается warnings, то есть Perl::Critic :-) Но для двухстрочной утилиты на коленке не вижу ничего страшного и в -w.

Comment: Бóльшая часть кода, которую написал Asid в своём вопросе, особой роли не играет — ведь по сути его интересовало то, как работают регулярные выражения. Так что от упрощения код не особо пострадал.

Тернарный оператор ?: есть и в C, но им не все пользуются :-)